# Rails encoding error. HAML issue I think

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, haml

I'm on rails 3.2.1 using postgres with pg 0.13.2 and haml 3.1.4.
DB encoding is "unicode" which I'm pretty sure is the same as "UTF-8" to postgres
Meta tag has charset=utf-8 (on both form page and display page) and the form has accept-charset="UTF-8"

I'm getting the "incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8" error in my production environment (Heroku cedar) and I've tried a bunch of fixes so far but don't really understand what's going on. Dev environment doesn't cause the problem.

The string causing the problem has an apostrophe copy/pasted from Word. If I remove the character everything renders fine but this is user submitted content so it's sure to break again in the future.

From a Heroku consol, calling string.encoding.name returns "UTF-8" and using force_encoding("UTF-8") in the view makes no difference.

But, if I use a haml filter (like :markdown) on the string it all renders fine.
Also, changing the view to erb fixes the problem.

Any Ideas? It's not really feasible to use filters everywhere and I want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Is the character in the database or is it in the HAML template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr
Switched to the rdiscount parser and everything works now.

Longer Version:
I'm still not exactly sure what is going on but I know it's in the parser (rpeg-markdown gem).

Another bit of text on the production page had a weird Word apostrophe and that seemed to be the issue. If I wrapped both strings in :markdown filters it all worked, but if either wasn't in a filter I got the encoding error even though everything is utf-8.

I switched to rdiscount and now it works whether or not one (or both) of the blocks are wrapped in a :markdown filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that the data you're getting out of the database is set with the proper encoding. The database encoding may be different from the database connection encoding if you haven't specified the right options in your `database.yml` file. For instance, you might need:

```
development:
  encoding: utf-8
```

Ensure that the value you retrieve through this connection is encoded properly:

```
my_model.my_attribute.encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

If you have a `BINARY` type field you might get `ASCII-8BIT` regardless of the settings. You can try and force-convert this or you can try and fix the column type. Force-encoding is usually the easiest:

```
my_model.my_attribute.force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Remember that `force_encoding` doesn't actually convert, it just changes the way the string is interpreted.

Comment: I've done/checked everything you mentioned as the original question states.

Comment: There's got to be a value in there somewhere where that isn't set properly. Does this occur if you use any unicode character like ☃ or is it specific to the pasted Word-style ’ character?